# how to get inputstream from class file existed in other project

Tags: java, inputstream, aop, javassist, getresource

I am trying to get inputstream from class file of the other project.

I am using eclipse. The output folder is:

`mycurrentproject/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes`.

The export library folder is:

`mycurrentproject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`.

When I print "java.class.path", I got this:

`D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;`

My environment variable of CLASS PATH of WINDOWS system is:

`.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;D:\work\workspace\myjar`

My code in package `action` to get resource stream is:

```
classfilePath = "/cc/Person.class";
InputStream isInputStream = ModifyMethodTest.class.getResourceAsStream(classfilePath);
```

Package `action` is outputed in "mycurrentproject/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes". `action.jar` is exported in "mycurrentproject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib".

When `cc/Person.class` in "mycurrentproject/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes", I got right result. When `cc/Person.class` in "mycurrentproject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" or in "D:\work\workspace\myjar". `isInputStream` got null. I want to get inputstream form a class file in the other project. The class file maybe in a folder or in a jar file in the target project folder. There should be many classes or jar files in that project. How to do that? For now, and for simple, I test my idea as above to put `cc/Person.class` in "D:\work\workspace\myjar". But It failed either. Any one have similar experience or advices? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
classfilePath ="file:D:/work/workspace/myjar/cc/Person.class"; 
URL[] urls = new URL[] { new URL(classfilePath) }; 
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls); 
InputStream isInputStream = ucl.getResourceAsStream(classfilePath);
```

Here isInputStream still got null. The parameter of getResourceAsStream() is `String name`. What could be? Something like relative path? Any references?

**EDIT2:**

It works with code as follow:

```
String Path1 = "file:D:/";
String Path2 = "work/workspace/myjar/cc/Person.class";

URL[] urls = new URL[] { new URL(Path1) }; 
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls); 
InputStream isInputStream = ucl.getResourceAsStream(Path2);
```

Comment: `classfilePath ="file:D:/work/workspace/myjar/cc/Person.class"; URL[] urls = new URL[] { new URL(classfilePath) }; URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls); InputStream isInputStream = ucl.getResourceAsStream(classfilePath); ` Not work.

Comment: I have edited to my question.

Comment: It works with code in **EDIT2**. I just don't know why.

Comment: Yes, do you have any references about the reason of this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `URLClassLoader`.  Once you've established it, call:

```
getResourceAsStream("/work/workspace/myjar/cc/Person.class")
```

For the `InputStream`.